# AngularJS append html to dom element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Im working on a small web app, and there is a side menu that has nav links in it. Each link when clicked pulls out a hidden panel and should display a list of items specific to that link.

I have most of the functionality working except Im stuck on how to append either a templateURL or just html to the panel.

Any guidance would be great.

heres what I have so far:
html

```
<!-- Pullout menu -->
 <nav id="sidebar-pullout">
   <div id="menu-list"></div>
</nav>
```

app.js

```
var configApp = angular.module("configApp", ['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap'])

.config(function($routeProvider){
   $routeProvider..when('/organizations', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard/organizations/organizations-title.html',
        controller: 'OrganizationController',
        activetab: 'organizations'
    })
      .otherwise( {redirectTo: '/dashboard'} );
  });

// Side Nav Link Controllers
   configApp.controller('OrganizationController', function($scope) {});
   configApp.controller('SideNavCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
  $scope.isActive = function(route) {
    return route === $location.path();
  }
 });

 // adding html to the menu-list
 configApp.directive('menu-list', function(){
  return {
    template: '<span ng-transclude >append som html here</span>',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    controller: 'OrganizationController'
  };
 });
```

Comment: What HTML or template do you want to append ? I don't think it's quite clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: For now I am just trying to append any html, later I will have the content that goes there

Comment: 1. What stops you from appending any HTML then ? 2. Are you aware of the use of `ngTransclude` ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way you might be able to go about it. By keeping a reference to menu items and contents. You could keep the side panel content in separate HTML files.

```
configApp.directive('menuList', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    link: function(scope, el, attr) {

        var activeId = null;

        scope.showContent = function(id) {
            activeId = id;
        };

        scope.isActive = function(id) {
            return activeId === id;
        }

        scope.menuItems = [{
            id: 'item1',
            name: 'Menu Item 1',
            content: 'path/to/menuItem1content.html'
        }, {
            id: 'item2',
            name: 'Menu Item 2',
            content: 'path/to/menuItem2content.html'
        }]
    }
  };
});
```

Then in you HTML maybe something like this.

```
<div menuList>
  <nav id="sidebar-menu">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in menuItems">
            <a ng-click="showContent(item.id)">{{ item.name }}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div id="sidebar-content">
    <div class="content"
         ng-repeat="item in menuItems"
         ng-include="item.content"
         ng-show="isActive(item.id)"></div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

This is just an idea and you could use angular animation to animate the sidebar sliding and stuff.

Comment: On the directive, it needs to communicate with the controller: 'OrganizationController' because that is the click handler that triggers the side menu

Comment: Sorry I was just giving you a slightly different alternative to the logic of inserting the content. You can still handling you triggers in external controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying your `ng-transclude` directive on the wrong element. You are placing it on your `span` tag. Try something like this instead:

```
<div>
  <span>/*My template html here*/</span>
  <div ng-transclude></div>
</div>
```

It also looks like you're specifying your directive incorrectly. Try this:

```
configApp.directive('menuList', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',    
    replace: true, // note: this syntax will soon be deprecated
    template: '<see above snippet>'
  };
});
```

In particular, notice `restrict`, which specifies how this directive will be used (A: attribute on html element, E: as an element itself, C: as a class). Here we are saying we want to use our directive as an element, `E`. Also, note that I used the name `menuList` instead of `menu-list`. AngularJS uses camel-case in directive definition, and maps the directive names found in the html into their camel case counterparts. So, in the html we will still use this directive like this: `menu-list`, but we will declare it using camel-case.
Hope this helps!

Comment: OK, thanks, I replaced what I had with this:  configApp.directive('menuList', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true, // note: this syntax will soon be deprecated
        template: '<div> <span>some text here</span> <div ng-transclude></div></div>',
        controller: 'OrganizationController'
    };
});

Comment: Didnt append the html like it should have, what did I miss?